# getting validation to check boxes

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

Hello all: I recently stumbled upon a question about form validation, which I'm currently trying to get working. I got the code from an answer and then customized it to more what I'm needing.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Validate(){
   if(!validateForm()){
       alert("Something happened");
       return false;
   }
return true
}
function validateForm()
{
    var c=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i].type=='checkbox')
        {
            if (c[i].checked){return true}
        }
    }
    return false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myForm" action="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png" onsubmit="return Validate()" method="get">
<input type="checkbox" name="live" value="yesno">You are alive.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="person">You are a person.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="eyes" value="color">Your eyes have color.
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: The image is just from a Google Image Search, and is on Wikipedia (I do not own it).

Now, when I originally entered the HTML from the answer into the Tryit Editor at W3 Schools, it would give me a "Something Happened" alert, or do nothing. (I think that's what is was supposed to do). 
Still, (now that I have my own questions) it will say "something happened" if nothing is selected, but no matter how many check (over 1 checked) it will just give me the image. Basically, what I want is it to check if ALL or ONLY SOME are checked. If all are checked i want one image, and if only some, I want a different one.
I hope this isn't too confusing, and I appreciate any help :)

P.S.:Here is the question where I got the code: [Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161956/javascript-checkbox-form-validation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for the script section, it will change the form's "action" attribute (which points the form to a the desired URL upon submitting) after validating how many checkboxes are checked:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Validate(formRef){
        var checkboxes = getCheckboxes(formRef);
        var checkedCount = validateForm(checkboxes);
        if(checkedCount == checkboxes.length){
            // All are checked!
            return true;
        } else if(checkedCount > 0) {
            // A few are checked!
            formRef.setAttribute('action', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Yahoo!_logo.svg/200px-Yahoo!_logo.svg.png');
            return true;
        } else {
            alert("Something happened");
        }
        return true;
    }

    function getCheckboxes(formRef) {
        var c = formRef.getElementsByTagName('input');
        var checkboxes = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<c.length; i++){
            if (c[i].type == 'checkbox')
            {
                checkboxes.push(c[i]);
            }
        }
        return checkboxes;
    }

    function validateForm(checkboxes) {
        var checkedCount = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
            if (checkboxes[i].checked){
                checkedCount++;
            }
        }
        return checkedCount;
    }
</script>
```

The form HTML should be updated to pass "this", the reference to the form object being validated, into the Validate() function, to avoid the need to query for it again:

```
<form name="myForm" action="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/30/Googlelogo.png" onsubmit="return Validate(this)" method="get">
```

Comment: so this worked with my stuff, but I'm adding other checkbox forms (I have multiple things that users will be checking for the requirements), and as soon as I add a second form, the only thing that comes up is the Yahoo. Any ideas?

Comment: The validate function is  specific to your first form's requirements. What are your second form requirements? We can take the next step based on that - making validate more generic or writing a new validate function.

Comment: For the next form I have two checkboxes, and I'll be adding a submit button. The two different images (one for all, one for some/none) are the same.

Comment: Perfect, as the requirements for the two images are the same, I have updated the code to localise the validation to the form that was submitted.

Comment: Also, (sorry if I'm bombarding) When I changed the 'alert("something happened"):' to the 'formRef.setAttribute('action', 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/24/Yahoo!_logo.svg/200px-Yahoo!_logo.svg.png');
            return true;'   so both "some" and "none" do the same thing, it will not open the image? Any ideas?

Comment: What you will want to do is create an image tag via `document.createElement()`, then set the src element to the image path, then append it to the document somewhere using `appendChild()` then return false instead of true. As for the else not doing anything, it is essentially doing `onsubmit='return false;'` which stops the form submitting.

Comment: okay so i've added document.createElement('img'), set the src of that to my image, and then in the same script appended it, then changed script you gave me to return false (some and none), but now only the ALL CHECKED img is coming up?

Comment: Would you mind posting a jsfiddle for the new images requirement and marking this solution as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Here is my jsfiddle with the drop down & checkbox forms, it also has the scripts you gave me: [link] (http://jsfiddle.net/titaniumalexander/xC4B5/)

Comment: I have simplified the JS and it's now working on http://jsfiddle.net/jedifans/LcJAj

Comment: Thanks ill have to check that our when I get a chance I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this (will alert first option if one or more but less than 3 checked, will alert second option if exactly 3 checked):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="checkbox" name="live" value="yesno">You are alive.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="type" value="person">You are a person.
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="eyes" value="color">Your eyes have color.
<br>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" onclick="
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByTagName('input').length - 1; i++)
{
    if(document.getElementsByTagName('input')[i].checked)
{
    count += 1;
}
}
if(count >= 1 && count < 3)
{
    alert('First Option');
}else
{
    if(count == 3)
    {
        alert('Second Option');
    }
}" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should get you on the right path:

```
function Validate() {
  var checkboxes = processCheckboxes();
  if (checkboxes.all.length == checkboxes.checked.length) {
    alert("All are checked");
  } else if (checkboxes.checked.length > 0) {
    alert("Some checked");
  } else {
    alert("None checked");
  }
  return false;
}

function processCheckboxes() {
  var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
  var checked = [].filter.call( checkboxes, function( el ) {
    return el.checked
  });

  return { all: checkboxes, checked: checked };
}
```

You can then process the checked boxes in whatever manner you like before submitting.

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkeyes/Zcu7d/